# Renaming Multiple Files From Column

Tags: excel, vba

I know there are a few other posts with similar questions. However, I am having difficulties getting this to function correctly.

I have a sheet named 'data' and in column B from row to onwards is the file names
I want to rename them so it displays **Column B - Column C**

What I have currently is the following:

A button to select the folder:

```
    Dim sFolder As String

Public Sub cmdOpenFolder_Click()

    ' Open the select folder prompt
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End If
    End With

    If sFolder <> "" Then ' if a file was chosen
        Me.txtFolderPath.Text = sFolder
    End If

End Sub
```

Then I have another button to start the renaming process:

```
Private Sub cmdRenameFolder_Click()


Dim strfile As String
Dim filenum As String



strfile = Dir(sFolder)
Dim old_name, new_name As String


For i = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row
strOldDirName = sFolder & Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value
strNewDirName = sFolder & Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value
Name strOldDirName As strNewDirName
Next i




End Sub
```

However, I am getting the following error:

[image]

line highlighted after debug:

```
For i = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row
```

Comment: Any chance you could let us know what line causes the error?

Comment: sorry, it is 

For i = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row

Comment: Is the macro running in the same workbook where it exists?  If so, where is the button code?

Comment: Its a VBA form, thats launched from sheet1, the data is held in the other sheet named 'data'

Comment: Try:  `For I = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` Note the different workbook reference, and the different method for determing the last row (unless you truly need `xldown` for entries in column A that you want to ignore.

Comment: Also, are you writing this in VB or VBA?  Your tag indicates VBA, but the screenshot of your error message reflects Visual Basic. In VBA, this error means that the worksheet referenced `Worksheets(2)` does not exist.  But `ActiveWorkbook` is not a good way to refer to the workbook in which you wish to run the code.

Comment: its VBA - when i change the line to that it displays error: type mismatch

Comment: See my more detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is usually due to not properly defining the workbook/worksheet that you want to act on.

For the error message you are seeing, I suggest:

```
    Dim I As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
        For I = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   'run your renaming code

        Next I
    End With
```